# How do I import static assets in a static html page with webpack?

Tags: html, webpack, static-html

**Problem Context**

I have webpack working for compiling my typescript into javascript. Automatic reloading works when I change my typescript code. However, webpack is not watching my static html file.

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── index.html
│   └── style.css
├── src
│   └── index.ts
└── webpack.config.js
```

The problem is I need to make several changes in my `index.html` and webpack does not automatically detect those changes. And, if I refresh the html page, it seems to break webpack's webpack-dev-server.

**Expected Output**

I want everything to be in the `src` folder and when I run `webpack` I have a fully working static site in my `dist` folder. That is:

```
.                                      .
├── dist                               ├── dist
├── src                                │   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.html                     │   ├── bundle.js
│   ├── index.ts      npx webpack ->   │   └── style.css
│   └── style.css                      ├── src
└── webpack.config.js                  │   ├── index.html
                                       │   ├── index.ts
                                       │   └── style.css 
                                       └── webpack.config.js
```

The files in the `dist` folder might have hashed filenames. I'm not worrying about that step for now though. I expect that webpack will go through my files and make sure they link to the correct resources. So if webpack were to give `style.css` a hashed name, the href in `index.html` would be updated.

**Current Output**

My current solution outputs both `index.html` and `bundle.js`, but *I cannot get it to copy `style.css` into the `dist` folder.* My current `webpack.config.js` looks like the this:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist'
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]' },
                { loader: 'extract-loader' },
                { loader: 'html-loader' }
            ]
        }
      ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

And my `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>stuff</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `index.ts` contains:

```
import './index.html';
```

**What I Tried**

At first I tried just adding an import for my css into my `index.ts`:

```
import './style.css';
```

But this did not work. Next I looked at the html-loader documentation, and it seemed to hint at what I'm looking for:
[image: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/]
However, I've read that inlining loaders like that is deprecated, and looking through the source there doesn't seem to be any configuration option for interpolation. I tried to do it as described in the documentation anyways, but it either simply does not work, or gives me some error message about `require` not found (I can't seem to reproduce that error though). My `index.html` contained:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${require(`style.css`)">
```

and `index.ts` contained:

```
require("html-loader?interpolate=require!./index.html");
```

How do I get webpack to move my `style.css` to the dist folder?

I have the hunch I'm misunderstanding how webpack is supposed to be used. When I have something working can I post my webpack config on the code review stack exchange to get help creating a more idiomatic webpack config?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041902/webpack-not-copying-css-into-dist? Seems like a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. When creating a CSS file, try using MiniCssExtractPlugin to write CSS to a new file
   import './style.css'; - this should work, but write CSS inline in the head of html.

   { use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'] }
2. For file name pattern: [name].[contenthash].bundle.js
3. Use HtmlWebpackPlugin for auto updating [contenthash]

   ```
    const plugins = () => {  
      const result =  [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       template: "./index.html", // this file will be used as html and all css/js will be automaticly included
      })
   ]}
   ```